# Solving a Differential Equation by Laplace Transform: $ty''(t)+(1-n)y'(t)+y(t)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solve the initial value problem
\begin{cases}
ty''(t)+(1-n)y'(t)+y(t)=0~~~~~~~~(n=2,3,4...)\\
y(0)=0,~~~~y'(0)=0
\end{cases}

I have tried this:
Laplace Transform.

$\mathcal{L}[y(t)]=Y(p)\\
\mathcal{L}[y'(t)]=pY(p)\\
\mathcal{L}[y''(t)]=p^2Y(p)
$

Then:
$$ty''(t)=-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dp}[p^2Y(p)]$$

Then:  $$
\frac{\mathrm d Y}{Y}=\frac{p^2}{1-(n+1)p}\mathrm d p$$

But I don't know what to do then.

In my textbook, the answer is :

$$y(t)=C\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(k+n)!}t^{k+n}$$ C is an 
arbitrary constant.

Comment: The RHS of the last equation is upside down.

Comment: Does the trivial solution $y(t)\equiv 0$ work?

Comment: Assuming that $p^2Y^\prime = (1-(n+1)p)Y$, you may now solve for $Y$:$$\ln(Y) = \int \frac{1}{p^2}-\frac{(n+1)}{p}dp = -\frac{1}{p}-(n+1)\ln(p) + \ln(C) \Rightarrow Y = Ce^{-\tfrac{1}{p}}p^{-n-1}$$. Now you "just" have to perform the reverse Laplace Transform on Y.

Comment: @糯米非米 In fact the trivial solution $y(t)=0$ works just fine... Did you forget to add a RHS to the equation? Or the initial conditions are different from the ones you posted?